# How to disable plug in power source sound while headphone is plugged in?

Tags: sound, headphones

I want to disable the "power source plugged/unplugged notification sound" when I have my headphones plugged in.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This maybe more simple than what you were looking for but you could always just go to system settings > sound > sound effects tab > then lower the alert volume.

Comment: This is also valid on 14.04  and 16.04 where there's also a Mute checkbox for alerts.